# several contour plots in the same figures

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have several 3d functions. I would like two plot the contour plots of them in the same figure to see the difference between them. I expect to see some crossings between contours of two functions. Here is my code:

```
plt.contour(xi, yi, F)
plt.contour(xi, yi, F1)        
plt.show()
```

But, it seems that the first one is erased at the end, since I see only one function without any crossing of contours. Is it possible to figure this out somehow?

Comment: Is `plt` a class? What `contour()` method do? Returning self? or adding the data to a list in plt?

Comment: Good question. plt is imported from matplotlib.pyplot I think it can return some value. I saw it in examples. I do not know actually

Comment: I'm not familiar with mathplotlib, but my guess is, that first you have to create an instance: `p_instance = plt()` and than call the methods on this instance: `p_instance.contour(xi, yi, F)` and at last, call the show: `p_instance.show()`

Comment: plt is the usual way to import matplotlib.pyplot. So it's a module and it's instanced at import.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did a quick test and I see both contours. The fact that they use common colors can be misleading. Try this :

```
plt.contour(xi, yi, F, colors='red')
plt.contour(xi, yi, F1, colors='blue')
plt.show()
```

A self-contained example :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
Y = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)

x,y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)

f1 = np.cos(x*y)
f2 = x-y

plt.contour(x,y,f2,colors='red')
plt.contour(x,y,f1,colors='blue')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I will try, but, independently of colors, there should be crossings of contours in my case which i see in octave.

Comment: I've added an example script so you can check for yourself.

Comment: Yes, that's working. thank you! Your answer has helped me to realize that I forgot to change one of the functions so I used two equivalent ones.

Comment: Weird, got hit by this today, only the first plt.contour() call is visible and not any subsequent...