# Plotting convergence of points on top of a contour plot in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, graphing

I have made a contour plot in Python for an optimization algorithm. Now, I am having trouble plotting the iterative points in Python. My (x,y) points are stored as vectors within an array. Here is an example of such:

`[array([-1, -2]),
 array([ 0.93396226, -0.45283019]),
 array([2.86792453, 1.09433962]),...]`

How could I plot each of these points on top of my existing contour plot using matplotlib?

Further explanation: I have this array of arrays. They represent x- and y-coordinates. I want to put these (x,y) coordinates on top of my contour plot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [several contour plots in the same figures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750829/several-contour-plots-in-the-same-figures)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you are looking for something like that:

```py
import pylab as plt

# ....

a = [array([-1, -2]),
 array([ 0.93396226, -0.45283019]),
 array([2.86792453, 1.09433962]),...]
x = array(a)[:, 0]
y = array(a)[:, 1]

# some contourf stuff

plt.scatter(x, y)
```